# Rendering URL through valueBox() or renderValueBox()

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I want to render a website through 'valueBox' as a hyperlink. Here below is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "sam"),
  dashboardSidebar( ),
  dashboardBody(
           fluidRow(
      valueBox("100", subtitle = tags$p("Attendance", style = "font-size: 
200%;"),
           icon = icon("trademark"), color = "yellow", width = 4,
           href = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/")
    ) )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I don't know how to code for rendering URL through a valueBox() or renderValueBox().

As of now the URL/website is displaying on the existing window. I want the URL/website should be display in a pop-up window.

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `valueBox` inside an `a` tag. In the tag you can set `target = "_blank"` to open the link on a new window or tab.

```
tags$a(
  href = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/", # Link to open
  target = "_blank", # Open in new window
  valueBox("100", subtitle = tags$p("Attendance", style = "font-size: 200%;"),
           icon = icon("trademark"), color = "yellow", width = 4)
)
```